# What is the value of the following integral? ( including the inverse of the CDF of the standard normal distribution)

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

What is the value of the following integral?

$$f(\alpha)=\int_0^\alpha [b-c \Phi^{-1}(1-\beta)] d\beta$$

where $0 \le \alpha\le 1$ , $b$ and $c$ are constants, and [$\Phi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution.) is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the standard normal distribution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CDF of a normal function is given by

$$\Phi(u) = \frac12 \left [1+\operatorname*{erf}{\left (\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \right )} \right ] $$

So let $u = \Phi^{-1}(1-\beta)$; then $d\beta = -\Phi'(u) du = -\frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-u^2/2} du$.  The integral then becomes

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)}^{\infty} du \, (b-c u) e^{-u^2/2}$$

which I think you can take from here. I get that the integral is equal to

$$\alpha b - \frac{c}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\left [\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha) \right ]^2/2}$$

Comment: I think it would become $$-\frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)}^{\infty}  \, (b-c u) e^{-u^2/2} du$$

Comment: @Alex: I found that I reversed the order of the integration limits; hence, the minus sign disappeared.

Comment: oh sorry! you are right!